# How Auto Deploy Java Web Service without Restart Service

Tags: java, web, service, deployment

Nowadays, after completing any new code/fix bugs of my project, manually export `.war` file and upload to server for redeploying. Then needs to restart service to take affect. For one day, many updated features are done and redeploy many times.

What to be needed is to auto deploy (Continuous Integration/Continuous delivery) without restarting web service. [Currently, our web service is developed by using Spring RESTFul & Hibernate, Tomcat & Ubuntu Server].

Comment: do you want hot deployment?

Comment: Yes, yet need to deploy without restart service again and again because it can cause the problem to the production which is being used by the users.

Comment: If you don't want to restart the entire web server, that is pretty easy to do. But depends on how your webapp is deployed. If it is deployed as a war file, then you must upload the updated war file and 
If your webapp as an exploded war file, then you can update specific files within the webapp directory with limitations. However, I would advise against this for production, as it will become extremely difficult to tell what is actually running in production.  See [how-to-enable-hot-deploy-in-tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32459047/how-to-enable-hot-deploy-in-tomcat)